# Variable assignment in haskell

Tags: haskell, conditional-statements

I'm trying to write a helper function that takes in a string and if the string has multiple spaces it turns it into just one string. Here is the code:

```
getSpaces :: String -> String
getSpaces index = 
    if (length index) == 1 then index
    else
        if isInfixOf " " index then index = " "
        else index
```

When I try to load my module into GHCI I get the error:

```
Prelude> :l Utilities
[1 of 1] Compiling Utilities        ( Utilities.hs, interpreted )

Utilities.hs:55:42: error:
parse error on input ‘=’
Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block?
e.g. 'let x = 5' instead of 'x = 5'
   |
55 |        if isInfixOf " " index then index = " "
   |                                          ^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Why am I not able to reassign index to a single space?

Comment: Because reassigning is fundamentally impossible in Haskell. All variable are immutable. That is rather logical since Haskell is a lazy language and hence if objects were mutable, then the behavior would be completely unpredictable.

Comment: Is is rather weird to name a string `index` by the way.

Comment: Hi @DanHessler, you seem to be a Haskell beginner! If you're looking for a good text for totally new Haskell programmers, I'd recommend [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why am I not able to reassign index to a single space?

Because in Haskell you are unable to reassign anything. In fact you never even *assign*, you *declare* (that is something related, but different). Even in some cases where it might perhaps look like you reassign variables (like in `do` blocks, you do not reassign, but you *shadow* variables by declaring a new one with the same name, again this is a bit related, but there are a lot of cases where we see different behavior, for example in a loop, we can not shadow the variable every iteration).

To answer your question, you probably want to return a string with one space, we can do that by writing:

```
getSpaces index = if (length index) == 1 then index else
                                 if isInfixOf " " index then " " else index
```

But nevertheless this is still rather inelegant, as well as it is rather unsafe since in case of an infinite `String`, this will start looping: the `length` keeps looping until the list (of characters) is exhausted, and it is possible that this never happens. Furthermore even if it does not get stuck in an infinite loop, then still it is not advisable, since it runs in *O(n)* (with *n* the length of the list). So for long lists, this is inefficient.

Usually in Haskell, one uses a combination of *patterns* and *guards* to distinct between possible values. Your case can be mapped to:

```
getSpaces :: String -> String
getSpaces st@[_] = st
getSpaces st | isInfixOf " " st = st
             | otherwise = " "
```

This will still loop however, in case the list has infinite size, sinze `isInfixOf` keeps looking for a space, until it has found one, or the `String` is exhausted.

Since `isPrefixOf` with as search pattern a string with *one* character in fact means that we look if the string contains a space, we can replace that with `elem` and look for the character `' '`:

```
getSpaces :: String -> String
getSpaces st@[_] = st
getSpaces st | elem ' ' st = st
             | otherwise = " "
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a fix, instead of changing index, I am just returning a single space.

Insead of:

```
if isInfixOf " " index then index = " "
```

I did:

```
if isInfixOf " " index then " "
```

So I just return the space.